# AEM login with facebook not working

Tags: aem

On AEM 6.1 instance I am trying to login using facebook.

Facebook login page opens up successfully. However when I key in any facebook credentials it gives me an authentication failed message and the url is appended with http://localhost:4503/ etc/cloudservices/facebookconnect/PROD_Facebook_APP.login.html//callback/j_security_check?code=AQAIAv.....(mix of alphabets and numbers).

This was working earlier. I dont see any error mesage on the logs and on developer tools
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Have you checked your cloud configuration for the Facebook connection? Is the configuration ok?

Comment: I see this below error when I key in the credentials on the facebook login window.  com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth.impl.OAuthAuthenticationHandler extractCredentials: Failed to retrieve user identification; cannot authenticate